# Error 404. Where can I learn about file tree structures and how a server reads assets? Having a lot of trouble

Tags: reactjs, browser, server, webpack, http-status-code-404

I just tried up deploy my React app for the very first time and spend 6 hours on it. Very discouraged, as I have been trying to deploy a simple one page react app and I couldn't do it.

First I tried to deploy to heroku, then to gh-pages

I think I got some hints as to the culprit from chrome dev tools. When I look at the sources tab, it looks like the browser is expecting what I put in the browser URL bar to be the actual names of the files in my file tree.

For instance, I was using react-router, and I had a route called /users/:id/dashboard.  So let's say the full app was http://myapp.com/users/:id/dashboard.

The Error I kept getting, probably over 500 times, was error 404 meaning not found. This means that the browser was looking for a file called myapp/users... when in fact, users was just simply a route. In other words the only entry point was supposed to be http://myapp.com/.... and anything after that should have been manipulated by the script file.

Anyways... this was a terribly frustrating experience to say the least. My app works perfectly in development, but in production mode error 404 is my enemy. I could really use some good resources for increasing my skills in this arena. Something that has to do with how a server serves up files, how the browser interacts with assuming what files will be served based on the URL, etc.

I appreciate it so much. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Work in development, but not  in production. The problem should be a path error, probably occurs in your `webpack.config.js` for production or `server.js`.

Comment: I am using create-react-app so I do not have a webpack config. I mean I do, but I don't even manipulate it. I just follow the bootstrapped way they have put it together to deploy an app.

Comment: You may offer the download link of your app codes for debugging.